# path \ and / in windows compared to VS code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, path

If I browse to a file (such as my python exe path) in file explorer (Windows) and click `copy path` i get this:

```
"C:\Users\User_one\Local\envs\lon\python.exe"
```

When run a file in VScode i see the executable path as this:

```
c:/Users/User_one/Local/envs/lon/python.exe
```

Why does VS code show forward slashes `/` whereas windows file explorer path is backward slashes `\` ?

Which is the correct (or preferred) one to use when referencing a file ?

Comment: both formats are accepted by windows. The "/" one is less error prone with escape sequences. The "\\" one is native windows and source of all kind of issues

Answer (score 0):

The correct one is not writing/hardcoding  the path, but creating it with the os library

```
import os
file=["C:", "Users", "User_one", "Local", "envs", "lon", "python.exe"]

print(os.path.join(*file))
```

Comment: this is appreciated, However, it does not answer the question of the difference between   /  and    \   ...  The first comment seemed to address this correctly.

Comment: I thought you were asking which one is the correct one. The correct one is the one made by os.path, and is correct not only on windows, but also in Linux, android, macintosh, or any computer running python

Comment: updated to "preferred" so to avoid being ambiguous.  For example, for quick testing, it is often the case that the user copy/pastes paths whereas the `os.path.join` although much better is comparatively verbose...   the natural copy\paste path from file explorer either leaves an the \ (which is the escape character) or needs to be rotated to a /.